# angularjs have a directive only apply for select controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a directive to implement scrolling on a page from an `a` to a `div`. Meaning that by clicking on an `a` looks like:

```
<a data-scroll-on-click="" href="#projects">Projects</a>
```

The page smoothly scrolls to:

```
<div id="projects">
```

To make this happen, I am using an attribute scroll-on-click via the following directive:

```
consortiumApp.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var idToScroll = attrs.href;
        element.on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var $target;
          if (idToScroll) {
            $target = $(idToScroll);
          } else {
            $target = element;
          }
          $("body").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, 1500, 'easeInOut
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

The `preventDefault` stops the router from kicking in.

The `a` with the `data-scroll-on-click` attribute is part of a navbar that I would like to include on other pages via `ng-include`.  However, this means that the `a` element will have the `scroll-on-click` attribute on pages where scrolling does not make sense.  Meaning that when the navbar is on other pages besides the main page, I want the anchors in it to function like links back to the main page and not to trigger scrolling.

I'm not sure what a good solution is: I'm not sure if it is possible to have `scroll-on-click` appear only when there is a certain active controller (a sort of conditional attribute)?  Or if it is possible to indicate the current active controller in a directive?

Worst comes to worst, I will just write two navbars - one for the main page that implements scrolling via a directive and one for subsidiary pages that implements linking via the router, but I have a feeling there is a more concise way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass boolean value along with the **data-scroll-on-click='true/false'** and check this in the directive if its true than proceed for scroll otherwise ignore it.

```
<a data-scroll-on-click="" href="#projects">Projects</a>
```

And

```
consortiumApp.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var idToScroll = attrs.href;
    var scroll_needed = attrs.scrollOnClick;
    if(scroll_needed === true){
      element.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target;
        if (idToScroll) {
          $target = $(idToScroll);
        } else {
          $target = element;
        }
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, 1500, 'easeInOut
      });
    }
   } 
  }
});
```

Comment: In your code the `scroll_needed` will be evaluated the first time directive is linked. This means that whenever user navigates away from main page (given page loaded in main page), directive is useless - it is already been initialized with `scroll_needed = true`.  It would be better to check `attrs.scrollOnClick` inside click handler to check current state of the app.

Comment: I have not tried it and if it does so your suggestion is good you can modified if have a working plinker or jsfiddle.

Comment: vote if answer is right and modify it if need some more correction.